# Error C4716: recordDownLog: must return a value

Tags: c++

```
void *recordDownLog(void *args) {
    while (!isFinished && !isWaitFinished) {

        isFinished = true;
        int i = 0;
        Sleep(sleepTime);
        while (i <= downNum) {
            if (downEndSize[i]<maxSize[i]) {
                isFinished = false;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (isFinished || isEnded) {
            if (isFinished) {
                writeDownFile(1);
            }
            else {
                writeDownFile(2);
            }
        }
        else {
            writeDownFile(0);
        }
    }
    cout << "end" << endl;
    isWaitFinished = true;
}
```

what should i return the value.

Comment: If there is no value to be returned, change the return type to `void`

Comment: FYI: `void *` is different from `void`

Comment: @InternetAussie: Answer in the answer section. This is the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to return any value, then change the return type to `void`. But if there is a missing return statement, then you'd know better than me where that should go. Maybe you want to return `args`, because that isn't used anywhere else and is the same type as the current return type.